# multiply numbers on all paths and get a number with minimum number of zeros

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning

I have `m*n` table which each entry have a value .

start position is at *top left* corner and I can go *right* or *down* until I reach *lower right* corner.

I want a path that if I multiply numbers on that path I get a number that have minimum number of zeros in it's right side .

*example:*

```
   1 2 100
   5 5 4
```

*possible paths :*

```
1*2*100*4=800
1*2*5*4= 40
1*5*5*4= 100
```

Solution : `1*2*5*4= 40` because 40 have 1 zero but other paths have 2 zero.

easiest way is using dfs and calculate all paths. but it's not efficient.

I'm looking for an optimal substructure for solving it using dynammic programming.

After thinking for a while I came up to this equation :

```
T(i,j) = CountZeros(T(i-1,j)*table[i,j]) < CountZeros(T(i,j-1)*table[i,j]) ?
                 T(i-1,j)*table[i,j] : T(i,j-1)*table[i,j]
```

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;
using Table = vector<vector<int>>;
const int rows = 2;
const int cols = 3;
Table memo(rows, vector<int>(cols, -1));

int CountZeros(int number)
{
    if (number < 0)
        return numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int res = 0;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        if (number % 10 == 0)
            res++;
        else break;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}


int solve(int i, int j, const Table& table)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0)
        return -1;

    if (memo[i][j] != -1)
        return memo[i][j];

    int up = solve(i - 1, j, table)*table[i][j];
    int left = solve(i, j - 1, table)*table[i][j];

    memo[i][j] = CountZeros(up) < CountZeros(left) ? up : left;

    return memo[i][j];
}
int main()
{
    Table table =
    {
        { 1, 2, 100 },
        { 5, 5, 4 }
    };

    memo[0][0] = table[0][0];
    cout << solve(1, 2, table);

}
```

[(Run )](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/665509132b0d7e7e)

But  it is not optimal (for example in above example it give 100 )

Any idea for better optimal sub-structure ? can I solve it with dynammic programming ?!

Comment: Please provide the code instead of relying on external links.

Comment: You could use Dijkstra's algorithm (or A*) twice. First pass, minimize the factors of two that you pass through. Second pass, minimize the factors of five that you pass through. The path with the minimum of the two aforementioned values is the path with the least number of zeroes at the end.

Comment: After a little thought, you wouldn't need to do two separate passes with Dijkstra's or A* -- you could make it in one go, if you're careful.

Comment: @user2899162 I'm not sure how to convert it to a graph for using dijkstra. I think using minimum number of factors between two adjacent cells for length of edges does not give optimal answer . right ?

Comment: A 1d vector to hold the entire matrix is more efficient than a vector of vectors. Use the calculation `x + y * width` to get the index. You can wrap this in a matrix2d class if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's reconsider the Bellman optimality equation for your task. I consider this as a systematic approach to such problems (whereas I often don't understand DP one-liners). My reference is the [book of Sutton and Barto](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/the-book.html).

The *state* in which your system is can be described by a triple of integer numbers `(i,j,r)` (which is modeled as a `std::array<int,3>`). Here, `i` and `j` denote column and row in your rectangle `M = m_{i,j}`, whereas `r` denotes the multiplication result.

Your *actions* in state `(i,j,r)` are given by going `right`, with which you end in state `(i, j+1, r*m_{i,j+1})` or by going down which leads to the state `(i+1, j, r*m_{i+1,j})`.

Then, the Bellman equation is given by

```
v(i,j,r) = min{ NullsIn(r*m_{i+1,j}) - NullsIn(r) + v_(i+1,j, r*m_{i+1,j})
                NullsIn(r*m_{i,j+1}) - NullsIn(r) + v_(i,j+1, r*m_{i,j+1}) }
```

The rationale behind this equation is the following: `NullsIn(r*m_{i+1,j}) - NullsIn(r)` denotes the zeros you have to add when you take one of the two actions, i.e. the instant penalty. `v_(i+1,j, r*m_{i+1,j})` denotes the zeros in the state you get to when you take this action. Now one wants to take the action which minimizes both contributions.

What you need further is only a function `int NullsIn(int)` which returns the nulls in a given integer. Here is my attempt:

```
int NullsIn(int r)
{
    int ret=0;
    for(int j=10; j<=r; j*=10)
    {
        if((r/j) * j == r)
            ++ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

For convenience I further defined a `NullsDifference` function:

```
int NullsDifference(int r, int m)
{
    return NullsIn(r*m) - NullsIn(r);
}
```

Now, one has to do a backwards iteration starting from the initial state in the right bottom element of the matrix.

```
int backwardIteration(std::array<int,3> state, std::vector<std::vector<int> > const& m)
{
    static std::map<std::array<int,3>, int> memoization;
    auto it=memoization.find(state);
    if(it!=memoization.end())
        return it->second;

    int i=state[0];
    int j=state[1];
    int r=state[2];

    int ret=0;
    if(i>0 && j>0)
    {
        int inew=i-1;
        int jnew=j-1;

        ret=std::min(NullsDifference(r, m[inew][j]) + backwardIteration({inew,j,r*m[inew][j]}, m),
                     NullsDifference(r, m[i][jnew]) + backwardIteration({i,jnew,r*m[i][jnew]}, m));
    }
    else if(i>0)
    {
        int inew=i-1;
        ret= NullsDifference(r, m[inew][j]) + backwardIteration({inew,j,r*m[inew][j]}, m);
    }
    else if(j>0)
    {
        int jnew=j-1;
        ret= NullsDifference(r, m[i][jnew]) + backwardIteration({i,jnew,r*m[i][jnew]}, m);
    }

    memoization[state]=ret;
    return ret;
}
```

This routine is called via

```
int main()
{
    int ncols=2;
    int nrows=3;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > m={{1,2,100}, {5,5,4}};    
    std::array<int,3> initialState = {ncols-1, nrows -1, m[ncols-1][nrows - 1]};

    std::cout<<"Minimum number of zeros: "backwardIteration(initialState, m)<<"\n"<<std::endl;
}
```

For your array, it prints out the desired `1` for the number of zeros.

Here is a [live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc5c710ea5bccca).

---

### EDIT

Here is an important thing: in production, you usually don't call `backwardIteration` as I did because it takes an exponentially increasing number of recursive calls. Rather, you start in the top left and call it, then store the result. Next you go left and down and each time call `backwardIteration` where you now use the previously stored result. And so on.

In order to do this, one needs a memoization concept within the function `backwardIteration`, which returns the already stored result instead of invoking another recursive call.

I've added memoization in the function call above. Now you can loop through the array from left top to right bottom in any way you like -- but prefereably take small steps, such as row-by-row, column-by-column, or rectangle-for-rectangle.

**In fact, this and only this is the spirit of Dynamic Programming.**

Comment: @omid: Note that `r` is not the best variable to include in the state, since it carries irrelevant information. Actually, I think the idea given by @sberezin is pretty optimal: just keep track of the number of `2`'s and `5`'s in the prime factor decomposition of your current result, i.e. the state variable would be `(i, j, nTwos, nFives)` This you probably avoid calculating the same result repeatedly.

Comment: actually this code is simply a brute force that memorize irrelevant stuffs! It just store the i,j with different values for r.  and never use momoization table, (look at the result : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1952a5fe2b273fd)

Comment: @omid: this is what I meant with "loop through the array from left to right". When you call the `backwardIteration` from the lower right element, it *calculates* all and stores it on-the-fly, but it never looks up a stored result (this is what I did and what might also be advantageous for a small array such as this one).

Comment: @omid: on the other hand, you can start from top-left and then -- as written -- traverse the array "row-by-row, column-by-column" or whatever. Then you'll always use the previously stored result. I don't know which way of traversal steps is optimal, but as long as you go in small steps towards the bottom-right element it should work always well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ty . It was my mistake I didn't read your answer carefully. just one thing more, shouldn't the find/memoization section be something like this : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11aba0a92f2d85de ?(I think checking r in memoization table is not necessary ) It seems working fine http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/406a07210bb71965

Comment: No no, I share your confusion by now. I'll rethink the role of this r and if I was successful I'll refigure my answer (just unaccept my answer). But up to now I think you can't leave the `r` out, since it matters (or more detailed, the 2's and 5's in it) -- one obtains different optimal ways depending on the `r`.

Comment: yeah you are right . can't we  just save number of 2's and 5's factors ?(since it use less memory and also the probability of using values in memo table is higher)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the idea -- namely to use a minimal state variable. Here such one consists of `(i,j,nTwos,nFives)`. And as you say, then the probability of using stored values again is higher (as there are less 2-and-5 states than whole numbers `r`).

Comment: @omid: actually, the *difference* in the numbers of 2 and 5 is enough to make decisions. I'll post a completely revised answer later as a new post.